# Dent in Lower Aluminum Frame Of Cannondale Cyclocross

Tags: frames, safety, cannondale

Recently purchased this bike second hand. How concerned should I be of this dent? It’s about midway down the lower frame.

[image]
[image]

[image: dent about midway down lower frame]

Comment: it's probably fine if you're just riding on the streets or level paths but if you're using it for cyclocross I'd be a little more concerned. that being said I'd avoid buying dented aluminum frames second hand.

Comment: Keep the photo you have. Take pictures at regular intervals (distances ridden) and check for changes. If changes become apparent, stop using and ask your LBS for advice.